# Why does my state variable from Context return "Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: ThemeContext"?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have been trying to create a simple theme changing functionality for my React app and I use DaisyUI's dataTheme to switch between premade themes.

I have set up a context for Themes and try to use a variable from it in my App.jsx but it always gives error "Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: ThemeContext".

I have tried moving my import out of {} such as "import { ThemeContext, ThemeProvider } from "./context/theme/ThemeContext"

but this time I encountered "Uncaught TypeError: useContext(...) is undefined". I don't know why I cannot use "useContext" in my App.jsx. I can use it in other components.

Here are the code blocks:

ThemeContext.jsx

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const ThemeContext = createContext();

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("synthwave");

  const setDark = () => {
    setTheme("dark");
  };

  const setCyberpunk = () => {
    setTheme("cyberpunk");
  };

  const setRetro = () => {
    setTheme("retro");
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider
      value={{
        theme,
        setDark,
        setCyberpunk,
        setRetro,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ThemeContext;
```

App.jsx

```
import "./App.css";
import { Theme, Button } from "react-daisyui";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/layout/NavBar";
import Footer from "./components/layout/Footer";
import Alert from "./components/layout/Alert";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Notfound from "./pages/Notfound";
import User from "./components/users/User";
import { GithubProvider } from "./context/github/GithubContext";
import { AlertProvider } from "./context/alert/AlertContext";

import { ThemeContext, ThemeProvider } from "./context/theme/ThemeContext";
import { useContext } from "react";

function App() {
  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <GithubProvider>
        <AlertProvider>
          <Theme dataTheme={theme}>
            <Router>
              <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col justify-between">
                <Navbar />
                <main className="container mx-auto px-3 pb-12 ">
                  <Alert />

                  <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/about" elemen t={<About />} />
                    <Route path="/user/:login" element={<User />} />
                    <Route path="/notfound" element={<Notfound />} />
                    <Route path="/*" element={<Notfound />} />
                  </Routes>
                </main>

                <Footer />
              </div>
            </Router>
          </Theme>
        </AlertProvider>
      </GithubProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ThemeDrop.jsx (a dropdown that I store in my navbar for easy access, everything works just fine in this one)

```
import React from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import ThemeContext from "../../context/theme/ThemeContext";

function ThemeDrop() {
  const { theme, setDark, setCyberpunk, setRetro } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return (
    <div className="dropdown">
      <label tabIndex={0} className="btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn ">
        Click
      </label>
      <ul
        tabIndex={0}
        className="dropdown-content menu p-2 shadow bg-base-content rounded-box w-52"
      >
        <li>
          <button onClick={setDark}>Dark Theme</button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a onClick={setCyberpunk}>Cyberpunk THeme</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a onClick={setRetro}>Retro THeme</a>
          <a>{theme}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ThemeDrop;
```

NavBar.jsx (where I put my dropdown)

```
import React from "react";
import { FaGithub } from "react-icons/fa";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import ThemeDrop from "./ThemeDrop";

function Navbar({ title }) {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar mb-12 bg-neutral text-neutral-content">
      <div className="container mx-auto">
        <div className="flex-none px-2 mx-2">
          <FaGithub className="inline pr-2 text-3xl" />
          <Link
            to="/"
            className="text-lg font-bold align-middle hover:bg-neutral-focus"
          >
            {title}
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1 px-2 mx-2">
          <div className="flex justify-end">
            <Link to="/" className="btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn">
              Home
            </Link>
            <Link to="/about" className="btn btn-ghost btn-sm rounded-btn">
              About
            </Link>
            <ThemeDrop />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

Navbar.defaultProps = {
  title: "Github Finder",
};

Navbar.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
};

export default Navbar;
```

I hope it was clear and I can get some guidance on this one. I must have made a very rookie mistake somewhere. I am able to achieve theme changing through state management but I am eager to use context api for this!

Appreciate any help

Comment: You can't use context outside of the provider. If you want to use the context in `App` the provider must be in the parent of `App`

Comment: @Konrad thank you so much! I have never knew that, I read countless docs about this I feel sad for missing it, I was getting extremely tired. I wrapped <App /> in main.jsx with ThemeProvider and it works! I wonder if it is a good convention though.